# Deleting duplicate values using time as criteria SQLite

Tags: python, database, sqlite

After some research and being an extremely beginner at SQL I couldn't figure out how to solve this task.

The data set has duplicate data (CAPTION_TEXT), which i would like to clean BUT only should be consider duplicate data, rows within a 2 segs of difference(CAPTION_START).

Example:
-Row N°9 and row N°19 have the same value.
-Difference between Row's N°9 and Row's N°19 Caption_start <2 seconds.
-There is a duplicate. It must be deleted.

[image]

Comment: Which of the 2 should be deleted?

Comment: the second one if it's easier even I could insert the new data (only one of them) into a new table. thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `ID` is the primary key of the table, you can use the function `julianday()`:

```
DELETE FROM tablename AS t1
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 
  FROM tablename AS t2 
  WHERE t2.ID <> t1.ID
    AND t2.CAPTION_TEXT = t1.CAPTION_TEXT
    AND julianday(t1.CAPTION_START) - julianday(t2.CAPTION_START) BETWEEN 0 AND 2.0 / (24 * 60 * 60)
)
```

If you want to insert the rows in a new table:

```
INSERT INTO new_table (ID, CAPTION_START, CAPTION_END, CAPTION_TEXT) 
SELECT * FROM tablename AS t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 
  FROM tablename AS t2 
  WHERE t2.ID <> t1.ID
    AND t2.CAPTION_TEXT = t1.CAPTION_TEXT
    AND julianday(t1.CAPTION_START) - julianday(t2.CAPTION_START) BETWEEN 0 AND 2.0 / (24 * 60 * 60)
)
```

See a simplified [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=79787cbbcb1f6608fb70a36dcb2e42ee).